# Form Validation not working and keeping form from submitting

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, validation

I have a form that I am using to send texts. It worked up until I added in the validate code. Now the form won't submit and the validation doesn't work at all. I have the jQuery and validation libraries in the file.

I am not getting any errors for this. It simply does nothing when I hit submit. Does anyone see anything within my validation code or general code that is causing this form to not submit and/or for the validation to not work?

```
<form action="" method="POST" id="text-form">
        <label>Enter the number to send to
            <input type="number" name="number" placeholder="Phone Number" class="block" id="number">
        </label>
        <label>Choose their phone service provider
        <select class="block" id="carrier" name="carrier">
            <option></option>
            <option value="vtext.com">Verizon</option>
            <option value="vmobl.com">Virgin Mobile</option>
            <option value="sms.alltelwireless.com">Alltel</option>
            <option value="txt.att.net">AT&T</option>
            <option value="sms.myboostmobile.com">Boost Mobile</option>
            <option value="text.republicwireless.com">Republic Wireless</option>
            <option value="messaging.sprintpcs.com">Sprint</option>
            <option value="tmomail.net">T-Mobile</option>
            <option value="email.uscc.net">U.S. Cellular</option>
        </select>
        </label>
        <textarea placeholder="Your Message" class="block" id="message" name="message"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Send Text" id="submit-text">
        <p id="text-success">Your Message Sent Successfully!</p>
    </form>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $("#submit-text").on("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var number = $("#number").val();
    var carrier = $("#carrier").val();
    var message = $("#message").val();

    $("#text-form").validate({
      onfocusout: true,
      rules: {
        number: {
          required: true,
          minlength: 2
        },
        carrier: {
          required: true
        },
        message: {
          required: true,
          minlength: 2
        }
      },
      messages: {
        number: {
          required: "Please enter the party's phone number.",
          minlength: "The phone number seems a bit short, doesn't it?"
        },
        carrier: {
          required: "Please choose their carrier"
        },
        message: {
          required: "Please enter your message",
          minlength: "Your message seems a bit short. Please enter at least 2 characters"
        }
      },
      submitHandler: function(form) {


        $.ajax({
          url: "text-send.php",
          type: "POST",
          data: {
            "number": number,
            "carrier": carrier,
            "message": message
          },
          success: function(data) {
            //console.log(data); // data object will return the response when status code is 200
            if (data == "Error!") {
              alert("Unable to send email!");
              alert(data);
            } else {
              $(".project-container").addClass("removeClass");
              $("#text-success").show();
              $(".light-gray-container").hide();
            }
          },
          complete: function() {
            $('body, html').animate({
              scrollTop: $('#text-success').offset().top
            }, 'slow');
          },
          error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(textStatus + "|" + errorThrown);
            //console.log("error"); //otherwise error if status code is other than 200.
          }
        });
      }
    })
  });
});
```

Comment: you should put `$("#text-form").validate()` direct under `$(document).ready()`. not inside `button.click`.

Comment: I get unexpected string errors when I do that.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
$("#text-form").validate({
  onfocusout: true,
  rules: {
    number: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 2
    },
    carrier: {
      required: true
    },
    message: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 2
    }
  },
  messages: {
    number: {
      required: "Please enter the party's phone number.",
      minlength: "The phone number seems a bit short, doesn't it?"
    },
    carrier: {
      required: "Please choose their carrier"
    },
    message: {
      required: "Please enter your message",
      minlength: "Your message seems a bit short. Please enter at least 2 characters"
    }
  },
  submitHandler: function(form) {

    var number = $("#number").val();
    var carrier = $("#carrier").val();
    var message = $("#message").val();
    $.ajax({
      url: "text-send.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: {
        "number": number,
        "carrier": carrier,
        "message": message
      },
      success: function(data) {
        //console.log(data); // data object will return the response when status code is 200
        if (data == "Error!") {
          alert("Unable to send email!");
          alert(data);
        } else {
          $(".project-container").addClass("removeClass");
          $("#text-success").show();
          $(".light-gray-container").hide();
        }
      },
      complete: function() {
        $('body, html').animate({
          scrollTop: $('#text-success').offset().top
        }, 'slow');
      },
      error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(textStatus + "|" + errorThrown);
        //console.log("error"); //otherwise error if status code is other than 200.
      }
    });
  }
});
});
```

Comment: I received this error `jquery.validate.min.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: e[d].call is not a function`

Comment: Check your validation js file. whether you are using a correct version of js plugin.

Comment: I am using multiple ones. `<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.14.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
 <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.14.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.14.0/additional-methods.js"></script>
 <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.14.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>`

Comment: No need to use all. You should use only one. i.e. `http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.14.0/jquery.validate.js`

Comment: Gotcha...but still the validation doesn't work. I have this in my site in other places and it works fine and it worked fine the way I had it with the validation inside of the submit. It just isn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to change from handling the click event

```
$("#submit-text").on("click", function(event) {
```

to handling the submit event

```
$("#text-form").on("submit", function(event) {
```

Comment: Thanks. That cleared up the error and the form submits, but the validation doesn't work at all. Still no errors.